# jquery ui slider modify width according to children elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

i have jquery ui slider with a huge width in px.

`.scroll-content {width:2400px;}`

and structure:

```
<div class="scroll-pane ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
   <div class="scroll-content">
     <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header"><img src="img/img1.jpg" /></div>
     <div class="scroll-content-item ui-widget-header"><img src="img/img2.jpg" /></div>
   </div>
 <div class="scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
  <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

how could i get the width of the inside elements and put that width to the slider container?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this really. One is to loop through the `scroll-content-item` divs and add up the widths of each, applying that the the main `scroll-content` div.

```
var totalWidth = 0;

$('.scroll-content-item').each(function(){
    totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).width();
});

$('.scroll-content').css('width', totalWidth + 'px');
```

Comment: thank you @Steve!
i managed with this one, what do you think:

    `var total_width = 0;
    $('.scroll-content').find('img').each(function() {
    total_width += $(this).width() + 10;
    });
    $( ".scroll-content" ).css('width', total_width);`

Comment: Yeah that's ok...I'd avoid using find as well as your selector as it just adds to the processing. I'd go with `$('.scroll-content-item img')` which does the same thing in this case.

Comment: Great stuff, glad to help :)